# Lambda expressions (C++0x) not working in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, c++-cli, friend, managed-c++

If I write this

```
std::function<int()> myFunction = []() {return 42;};
```

in C++/CLI under VS2010 (in an MSTest unit test class, in case it matters), I get the compiler error C3809: `a managed type cannot have any friend functions/classes/interfaces`.

Is a lambda considered as a friend because it cooooould access local variables, even if it doesn't?

On the other hand, this works fine:

```
int ThatOldJokeAgain()
{
    return 42;
}
[...]
std::function<int()> myFunction2 = ThatOldJokeAgain;
```

Is there a way to make lambdas work in C++/CLI? Or is my error something completely different?

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, it does: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx#9034197

Comment: @Matteo: That question is about .Net lambdas (syntactic sugar for delegates), not the C++0x lambdas. Also, I'm asking this question because I have found nothing about this "friend" error message and lamba expressions.

Comment: sorry, I pasted the wrong link in the comment; previously I found another answer which had a working link to some official source stating that they were not supported in C++/CLI, but I can't seem to find it again. Anyhow, the duplicate linked at the top is exactly your problem (down to the exact error message).

Comment: @Matteo: Thank you, that is exactly it! Sorry, I didn't find it before asking.